# Yet Another ListView custom adapter getView called way too many times

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom adapter and getView is being called a ton of times on position 0.  I have read a bunch of similar questions and most of them point to setting height of ListView to be "wrap_content" as the culprit.  My ListView and rows are all set to fill_parent or match_parent, none of them are set to wrap_content.

While I am aware that getView can be called in any order and any number of times, it seems that I must be doing something wrong to produce this many calls for position 0 (see log below).  What are some other potential causes for getView being called so many times?

```
07-22 11:48:03.032: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 5
07-22 11:48:03.082: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.092: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.102: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.112: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.152: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.162: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.192: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.202: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.332: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 6
07-22 11:48:03.392: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.402: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.412: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.422: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.472: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.482: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.492: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.492: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.542: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.552: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.562: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:03.562: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.602: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 7
07-22 11:48:05.642: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.652: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.662: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.672: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view  for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.692: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.712: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.712: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.722: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.862: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 8
07-22 11:48:05.922: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.952: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.962: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:05.972: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.012: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.012: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.022: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.032: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.062: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.102: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.102: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.112: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.412: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 9
07-22 11:48:06.442: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.452: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.452: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.462: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.492: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.492: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.502: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.502: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.702: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 10
07-22 11:48:06.762: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.772: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.782: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.792: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.822: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.832: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.862: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.872: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.892: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.902: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
07-22 11:48:06.912: INFO/com.thisclicks.appdataroom(28989): Masonry adapter fetching view for position 0
```

Here is my ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/categorylist_divider"
          android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:clickable="false" android:divider="@color/categorylist_divider" android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="20dp" android:layout_below="@+id/header" />
```

And the row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#eeeeee">
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivHeader" android:background="@color/categorylist_divider"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:useDefaultMargins="true" android:clipChildren="false"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/masonryrow_layout" android:columnCount="3"
                android:rowCount="2" android:background="#eeeeee" android:layout_below="@+id/ivHeader">
</GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for getView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Masonry adapter fetching view for position %d", position));
    View vi=convertView;
    int rowType = determineRowType(position);
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Masonry adapter building view for position %d", position));
        vi = buildView(parent, rowType);
    }

    holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    int columnWidth = (parent.getWidth()-20)/holder.layout.getColumnCount();
    if(holder.columnWidth != columnWidth)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Column width mismatch, rebuilding view");
        vi = buildView(parent, rowType);
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }


    //hide header and footer spacing
    if(position != 0)
    {
        if(holder.ivHeader != null)
            holder.ivHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        if(holder.ivHeader != null)
            holder.ivHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }



    int rowCapacity = calculateRowCapacity(rowType);


    for(int i = 1; i <= rowCapacity; i++)
    {
        CellHolder cellHolder = holder.cells.get(i-1);
        int realPosition = calculatePosition(position, i);
        if(realPosition < data.size())
        {
            cellHolder.ivMediaTileThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cellHolder.tvMediaName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cellHolder.ivMediaTileCorner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Media media = data.get(realPosition);

            hydrateMediaTileView(realPosition, media, cellHolder);

        }
        else
        {

            cellHolder.ivMediaTileThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cellHolder.tvMediaName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cellHolder.ivMediaTileCorner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    return vi;
}
```

EDIT: Here is the complete layout that contains the listview (it is a ListFragment):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:clipChildren="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/categorylist_divider">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:clipChildren="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/header" android:background="#ca4f37"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ivBack" android:src="@drawable/category_title_bar_backarrow"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/tvHeaderText" android:textColor="@color/categorylist_headertext"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivBack" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp" android:textSize="@dimen/categoryList_headertext" android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ivHeaderPlus" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivBack" android:src="@drawable/title_bar_plus"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:id="@+id/btnLeft" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:background="@drawable/header_button_background" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRight"
                android:textSize="@dimen/headerButton_textSize"
                android:textColor="@color/categorylist_headertext"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Send"
                android:id="@+id/btnRight" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/header_button_background"
                android:textSize="@dimen/headerButton_textSize"
                android:textColor="@color/categorylist_headertext" android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@color/categorylist_divider"
              android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
              android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
              android:clickable="false" android:divider="@color/categorylist_divider" android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="20dp" android:layout_below="@+id/header" />
    <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/webView" android:layout_below="@+id/header" android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" android:layout_marginRight="40dp" android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try `android:layout_height="0px"` in your `ListView`

Comment: Setting android:layout_height="0px" makes the listview disappear

Comment: Post your layout. If your `ListView` is inside a `LinearLayout`, try to add the attribute `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: Posted, it is inside a relative layout along with a header

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out the culprit was in the ListFragment onCreate.  Dynamically setting the ListFragment's root LinearLayout to width of 0 was causing the issue.  Commenting this out fixed the adapter problem.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    inflater.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup mRootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.masonry_list, container, false);



    if(model != null && model.getFragmentWeight() != 0)
    {
        mRootView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, model.getFragmentWeight()));
    }

    return mRootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is, what are the potential causes of a list view calling getView too many times, the top three would be:

1.- Calling notifyDataSetChanged(); continuously forcing the adapter to redraw.

2.- Calling ListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter); repeatedly which tries to assign a new adapter every time, hence rendering it.

3.- Doing modifications on the layout holding the view causing the childs to redraw invalidating the current view state

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I too had problems with getView() being called way too many times in my adapter. I was using a ListFragment which comes with an underlying list. I did a lot of research to figure out how to change the layout of the underlying list. Eventually I stumbled upon this in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

I figured my problem was that the underlying list layout didn't have layout_width="match_parent" and layout_height="match_parent". I tried to set this in my java code, but I never really got this to work. Instead I tried another route, where I wanted to set the layout for the underlying list in the ListFragment from a layout xml file. This worked a lot better! It is explained a bit in the top of the above link.

My layout file (listview_listfragment_activity_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@id/android:list"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@id/android:empty"/>
```

Then I did an override of the onCreateView() method of my MainActivityListFragment like so, to return the correct layout when the ListFragment got created:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_listfragment_activity_main, container,  false);
}
```

In the getView() method of the adapter I added this line to check how many times the method was called, and finally it was only called once for every list item :)

```
Log.i("DEBUG", "Entered getView - position: " + position);
```